# R create binaries predictor from a corpus

Tags: r, text-mining, spam-prevention

I have a dataset of e-mails.

The outcome is 1 (spam) 0 (non-spam).
I have several categorical and numerical predictor. But I have another predictor which is the content of the e-mail.

In R, I would like to :

1. Put all e-mail together
2. Do some text processing with those mails (step1) [removing punctuation, streaming words (ie remove -ing, plural, etc), remove common words, remove capitalization (and maybe some more processing).
3. From the remaining word : take the top 10% more frequent word
4. For each of those most frequent word create a binary predictor (1 if the e-mail got that word , 0 otherwise)

Would such a package exist in R?

Comment: It really looks like a combination of typical string functions such as `paste()`, `grep()`, `strsplit()` and some summary like `table()`. All of them are from base package. Maybe you can provide an example and desired output? It'd be easier to answer this question with exact code to do so.

Comment: You should really take a look at `tm` library.